# problems of finding the summation, average, variance in Visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a vb.net 2010 form that will add a users input. I want to make a program that can calculate the summation, average, variance, and standard devation.... anyone can help in adding code and fixing the problem???? please help me....  I am trying to fix the problem but when I run the program there's an error"InvalidOperationException was unhandled(An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)"

Anyone can help me in fixing this problem?

```
Public Class Form1
Dim sum As Integer
Dim mean As Double
Dim x(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim TotalN As Double = InputBox("The total Number", "Enter a number")
    Dim sum As Single
    Dim b As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

    Dim counter As Integer
    For counter = 0 To b
        x(counter) = ListBox1.Items(counter)

        If (Val(x(counter)) = TotalN) Then

            sum = (sum + x(counter)) / TotalN

        End If

    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code and seeing on what line the 'Object reference' error occurs?

Comment: there's no error in my program but when you click the run button the massage will show"An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Take a copy of your code and any markup you have added to the webform. Delete the webform from your solution. Create a new web form, set it as the startup page and then see if you can run it as is without adding any new code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get the exception because the x array is created at the start of the program/form when the ListBox does not contain any items.

Try doing a `ReDim` of the array inside the `Button1_Click` method.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim sum As Integer
    Dim mean As Double
    Dim x(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click
        Dim TotalN As Double = InputBox("The total Number", "Enter a number")
        Dim sum As Single
        Dim b As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

        ReDim x(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) ' change the size of the array

        Dim counter As Integer
        For counter = 0 To b
            x(counter) = ListBox1.Items(counter)
            If (Val(x(counter)) = TotalN) Then
                sum = (sum + x(counter)) / TotalN
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```